# how many ways to partition a set with k subsets, each of fixed size?

Tags: combinatorics

if $(v_1,...,v_k)$ is a partition of $n$, how many ways $M((v_1,...,v_k),n)$ is there to create a set (partition) of $k$ elements, each of size $v_i$ , i=1,...,k from $n \geq k$ distinct elements ?

example

if n=3, we consider the 3 distinct elements a,b,c

M((1,1,1),3)=1  : {{a},{b},{c}}

M((1,2),3)=3 :  {{a,b},{c}}  ; {{a,c},{b}}   ;  {{b,c},{a}}

M((3),3)=1 :   {{a,b,c}}

Comment: once you have a subset of $v_1,...,v_k$ elements, you can create all the others by swapping elements between different sets,  so I think there may be a formula for $M((v_1,...,v_k),n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the $v_i$ are *distinct* then the answer is: $$\frac{n!}{v_1!\times\cdots\times v_k!}$$

More general if you have $n=n_1w_1+\cdots+n_mw_m$ with $n_i\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$, distinct $w_i$ and $w_i$ occurring exactly $n_i$ times in tuple $(v_1,\cdots,v_k)$ then multiple counting must be 'corrected' and the answer is:$$\frac{n!}{(w_1!)^{n_1}\times\cdots\times (w_m!)^{n_m}\times n_1!\times\cdots\times n_m!}$$
Here $k=n_1+\cdots +n_m$.

Answer (score 0):

The species here for distinct $v_k$ is $$\prod_{q=1}^k \mathfrak{P}_{=v_k}(\mathcal{Z}).$$
This gives the exponential generating function
$$G(z) = \prod_{q=1}^k \frac{z^{v_k}}{v_k!}.$$
The desired result is $$n! [z^n] G(z) = n! \prod_{q=1}^k \frac{1}{v_k!}$$ as claimed.